# Detecting a significant change in survey answers

Tags: chi-squared-test, survey, likert, quality-control

I conducted a user study where participants were asked to rate the relevance of search results on the following scale: "very unrelevant", "unrelevant", "relevant" and "very relevant". Every participant judged between 30 and 200 results.

I want to investigate the quality of the survey results so one step I took was to calculate the frequencies of participants to vote for an extreme judgement (very un/relevant) over the course of the study. I found that on the 200th judgement of an individual participant the chance was ~5% greater to do this.

Now I want to test if this change in behaviour is statistically significant. I did this by using a chi-squared test. I calculated the expected frequencies by using the mean values of the first 10 judgements.

My question: Is the chi-squared test an appropriate test for this scenario? What other (better fitting) tests can be applied?